# Add extra node from nodequeue in views before rendering views content

Tags: views

My need is that i made a block form views which show the content from content type blog, now i want to some extra node from nodequeue to that views block on given condition.

I am tried with [`hook_views_pre_render`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7), but didn't get anythings.

Thanks in advance

Comment: u can create a new view for blog content type with your conditions and use it instead of default one..

Comment: I am already created a view for blog content type and i want to add more node from nodequeue when content node less than 4 node.